# Docker compose build failed when trying to update git submodule from remote repo

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, git-submodules

I need help with docker compose (v2.5.0) and git submodules. It is big project with many microservices using JS. Some microservices have git submodule (the same one) inside. I created docker-compose.yml which builds the whole project. It works great when I'm pointing build context to local directory like:

```
some-service:
 build:
  context: /my/home/dir/some-service_dir
```

but when I'm trying to build from remote git repo

```
some-service:
 build:
  context: https://gitURL/some-service.git#branch
```

and the service have submodule inside, it crashes with `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` when tries to do `git submodule update`. I tried to specify the appropriate instructions in the docker file and  in the makefile alternately.
This service has .gitsubmodule file with right structure like

```
[submodule "name"]
    path = submoduleDir
    url = https://git.repo.url/mysubmodule.git
    branch = develop
```

all configs in .git are also correct, I suppose, cause it works great in other cases.
So I have no idea what happening and why it doesn't work only when context points to the remote git repo. Any suggestions?